# connect-to-oracle-db-9i server-using-ssh-tunnel-via-putty

Tags: ssh, configuration, oracle9i

I am trying to connect ORACLE DB behind NAT so i choose SSH TUNNEL via putty so here is the information

Global i p example: 122.54.34.12

LAN i p example : 192.168.3.103

ORACLE DB_PORT : 1521

and here is  putty ssh tunnel settings

```
L1521     122.54.34.12:1521
```

so i connected to global IP ssh session and every thing is ok tell now , but when i want to connect ORACLE DB via SQL console after ssh tunnel

```
sql > connect username/password@127.0.0.1/service-name
ERROR:
ORA-12170:TNS Connect timeout occurred
```

Answer (score 1):

Your settings must be:

`L1521   127.0.0.1:1521`

Comment: Thanks for your replay ,i had tried your answer ,but the new error is TNS 12541: Tns no listener ,and i tried Tnsping and its ok ,but with connect command the error shown above

Comment: Full output of tnsping, netstat -tnpl and iptables-save (or iptables -L) would be very useful to start with.